# Database Connection Error from Glue spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, vpc

I need to connect RDS Postgre db which is behind a VPC in a private subnet from Glue. I am not able to connect the db using Glue Connection which will be used in spark code in glue.

Comment: I am assuming you created a glue connection with the same VPC/Subnet/SecurityGroup settings. What error do you get when you test the connection?

Answer (score 0):

If you check Glue architecture, it spins up the servers in the VPC, subnet and security group that you select in the DB connection. 
So, if you want to access a RDS ensure that the VPC & subnet can access the RDS JDBC port.
Follow the [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/connecting-to-and-running-etl-jobs-across-multiple-vpcs-using-a-dedicated-aws-glue-vpc/) for details of setting up VPC and subnet for glue

Comment: Yes, I was able to connect the database with appropriate Network configurations. Thanks

Comment: @Umer select this answer if it resolved the issue you had

Comment: Event bridge is not able to read the database credentials from Secret Manager.